# Docker image not available for ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am working on a project which is based on ASP.NET Core 2.2.8, and I am planning to use docker for this project. The issue is I am getting this error when running the docker file

> mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.2: not found

I have read some posts that .NET Core 2.2 is **out of support** and the images are removed. And the option is to upgrade the project. In my case I cannot upgrade the project from .NET Core 2.2. The reason is we are trying to use the **Huawei** cloud service stage, for that the supported .Net core versions are 2.0.9 and later, and versions earlier than 3.0

https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/productdesc-servicestage/ss_productdesc_0001.html

Is there a way to add docker for my project?

Comment: I assume you have a not-Docker version running today somewhere where the 2.2 runtime is installed? Maybe you can find the relevant bits on that machine and put them into a docker image and get it to work.

Comment: I would recommend invest more time in finding out why you cannot update and search a possible way to do it. I think this is the better time invest then searching for workarounds just to bring old dotnet version back to life.

Comment: @Martin We are trying to use the **Huawei** service stage for that the supported .Net core versions are 2.0.9 and later, and versions earlier than 3.0.
https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/productdesc-servicestage/ss_productdesc_0001.html

Comment: @HansKilian Ah ok. Sounds like Huawei need to update their systems soon... But if you can deploy docker there maybe you can use the answer from Numb95 and just install the current runtime in dockerfile.

Comment: @Ameer - 
I would not recommend baseing a Production environment on a 3rd party maintaining a .NET base image. 1) when will this 3rd party suddently stop having the image available? 2) more importantly... what's in this base image? is it ONLY the official .NET code or has the 3rd party added something - like a backdoor? Use the official source for images, is my recommendation - and if your project is still using Core 2.2 - start upgrading. .NET 6 is out, .NET 7 is in preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the alternative docker images from the docker hub.

> docker pull vminnovations/dotnet-aspnet:2.2.8

> docker pull vminnovations/dotnet-sdk:2.2

Using the above mentioned images are simple and easy. I have created a test project and added the images. It is working fine

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend baseing a Production environment on a 3rd party maintaining a .NET base image. 

1) when will this 3rd party suddently stop having the image available?
2) more importantly... what's in this base image? is it ONLY the official .NET code or has the 3rd party added something - like a backdoor?

Use the official source for images, is my recommendation - and if your project is still using Core 2.2 - start upgrading. .NET 6 is out, .NET 7 is in preview.

Answer (score 1):

as you said, the 2.2 is [no longer supported](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). As I was stuck in a similar situation in one of my projects, I used [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/laptevss/dotnet-aspnet). It works fine but use it at your own risk.

As a plus, you can also use this `Dockerfile` for the base image of your project. It creates a big Docker image, but at least it works.

```
FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-scm
# Install .NET CLI dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libc6 \
        libgcc1 \
        libgssapi-krb5-2 \
        libicu57 \
        liblttng-ust0 \
        libssl1.0.2 \
        libstdc++6 \
        zlib1g \
        nuget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Install .NET Core SDK
ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION 2.2.300
RUN curl -SL -k --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && dotnet_sha512='1d660a323180df3da8c6e0ea3f439d6bbec29670d498ac884f38bf3cdffbb041c7afff66171cdfd24c82394b845b135b057404def1fce9f206853726382bc42b' \
    && echo "$dotnet_sha512 dotnet.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
# Configure web servers to bind to port 80 when present
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 \
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true \
    # Enable correct mode for dotnet watch (only mode supported in a container)
    DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true \
    # Skip extraction of XML docs - generally not useful within an image/container - helps performance
    NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip
```

Build it using this and use it in your project.

```
docker build -t dotnet:2.2 .
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The image link that you have provided is **not working**.
https://hub.docker.com/r/laptevss/dotnet-aspnet

Comment: Do you use this tag? ```laptevss/dotnet-aspnet:2.2.8-stretch-slim```

Comment: I have tried many times and got 404. But the link is working now, thanks :)